# How to load a property on demand?

Tags: matlab, oop

I want to load a property on demand but i cant get it working. 
I have a class with a transient property `foo`. So the property is not stored when the object is saved. When I use a method that is calling the property 'foo', I want that the value of foo is loaded from a separate mat file and stored into the object as long as it is in workspace.

I tried something with get and set methods but cant get it working. Is this possible? Or do I always add a line of code that is loading the property? The following code does not do what I want but it gives an indication what i tried.

In addition, the code below keeps loading the foo.mat file when the property is used. I want to load foo.mat only one time and store it as a property and retrieve the data from there instead of loading. The reason for my question is that the foo property is rather large i.e. a class with many properties in itself. I only want to load it when it is needed and dont want to store it in foobar class itself.

```
classdef foobar
    properties(Transient = true)
        foo
    end
    methods
        function value = get.foo(obj)
            if isempty(obj.foo)
                value = load('foo.mat');
                disp('load foo.mat');
            end
        end
        function obj = set.foo(obj,value)
            obj.foo = value;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: "Can't get it working" means...what exactly? Your example works fine.

Comment: Good point to explain it better. Using the script I posted, every time i execute for example, object.foo it loads the foo.mat file instead of only once.

Comment: A [Default Property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/specifying-properties.html#brqy3km-10) might be a better option.

Comment: I dont want a default property as it is pretty large. I only want to load it when it is called, and load it once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two major problems here:

1. In your `get.foo` method, once you load the value, you never update the value of `foo` in the object, so it remains empty.
2. Even if you tried to update `foo` in your `get.foo` method, it would still be empty in the *original* object because your `foobar` class is a [value class](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html). Methods that modify a value class object have to return the modified object as an output, because they are essentially modifying a *copy* of the object. A `set` method of a value class returns a modified object that is used to overwrite the original object, but `get` methods don't return modified objects (since they aren't generally expected to modify them). To get around that limitation, you'll need the reference-like behavior of a [handle class](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/handle-classes.html) (here's [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51294245/52738) you may want to take a look at for more background).

So, in order to get the behavior you want you'd have to implement `foobar` as a subclass of the handle class and update the `foo` field when you first load it:

```
classdef foobar < handle    % Inherit from handle class

  properties(Transient = true)
    foo
  end

  methods

    function value = get.foo(obj)
      if isempty(obj.foo)
        value = load('foo.mat');
        disp('load foo.mat');
        obj.foo = value;       % Update foo
      end
      value = obj.foo;         % Return current foo value
    end

    function set.foo(obj, value)  % Return value is unnecessary for handle class
      obj.foo = value;
    end

  end

end
```

This should now give you the behavior you want (i.e. `foo` is only loaded when it is first accessed).

**Note:** *Any* method that invokes `get.foo` will initialize `foo`. One method you may overlook, because it's created by default for a class, is the [`disp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/disp.html) method. The [default display for a class object](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/custom-display-interface.html#bt2_d3t) will show the class name followed by a list of non-hidden public properties *and their values*. Note what happens when I create an object of class `foobar` from above with and without a semicolon:

```
>> f = foobar;  % Display is suppressed
>> f = foobar

f = 

load foo.mat               % foo gets initialized...
  foobar with properties:

    foo: [1×1 struct]      % ...because its value is displayed here
```

If you want to avoid this, you can [overload the `disp` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/displaying-objects-in-the-command-window.html) for your `foobar` object so that displaying the object doesn't access (and thus initialize) `foo`. For example, you can add this method to the above `foobar` class:

```
    function disp(obj)
      disp('     foobar object');
    end
```

Now you won't initialize `foo` when displaying the object:

```
>> f = foobar

f = 

     foobar object  % foo not yet initialized
>> a = f.foo;
load foo.mat        % foo initialized because we accessed it
```

Comment: Your answer is almost what I want but the last note is an issue for me. Most of my methods, which call the property `foo`, live insite the object. I only want to load `foo` if a method is calling for it, so that the property `foo` is not loaded while an instance of `foobar` already exists.

Comment: @SGeurts: I added more detail to my note. All you should have to do is overload the `disp` method so that it doesn't access `foo`.

Comment: Great! The set method isnt even necessary for my purpose. I also discovered that showing the object in the Variables menu initiate loading `foo`. What I still dont understand is why a Handle class is needed instead of a Value class.

Comment: @SGeurts: I added some more detail about value and handle classes. Hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: Is there also a way to prevent loading the `foo` data while the Variables display is showing the `foobar` object?

Comment: I can set the property attribute Hidden to 'true', so it is solved.